# table() generating NAs when there are no NAs in the underlying data

Tags: r, na

I want to generate a column of counts of a particular variable. The easiest way seems to be using table(). For reasonably small amounts of data, there seems to be no problem.

```
A <- data.frame(A1 = sample(1:1000, 100000, replace = TRUE))
B <- data.frame(B1 = sample(1:1000, 100000, replace = TRUE))
C <- cbind(A, B)
C$countC <- table(as.factor(C$A1))[C$A1]

summary(C$countC)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 65      94     101     101     108     132
```

However, if I'm building a table from a larger set (note that now I'm sampling from 1:10k, rather than 1:1k), it generates NAs, despite there being no NAs in the data I'm building a table from:

```
A <- data.frame(A1 = sample(1:10000, 100000, replace = TRUE))
B <- data.frame(B1 = sample(1:10000, 100000, replace = TRUE))
C <- cbind(A, B)
C$countC <- table(as.factor(C$A1))[C$A1]

summary(C$A1)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1    2512    5005    5008    7502   10000 

summary(C$countC)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
1.00    8.00   10.00   10.18   12.00   25.00       7
```

The problem does not occur if the data are not in a data-frame.

```
A <- sample(1:10000, 1000000, replace = TRUE)
summary(table(as.factor(A))[A])
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
57      94     101     101     108     144
```

Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: I can't reproduce it... R 2.15.2. Maybe set a seed?

Comment: Thanks Frank. Try making the set to draw the samples from bigger (maybe 100k). We've replicated it on two machines so far with no seed setting.

Comment: Ah! Hello. It seems to only have thrown NAs only for the last few categories (in this case, only 99998, 99999 and 100000). That makes it manageable, but definitely not ideal.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce it. The main line -- `table(as.factor(C$A1))[C$A1]` -- is pretty cryptic to me. If you are just trying to merge back counts by group, there are other ways. I can show you the data.table way in three lines.

Comment: Frank-- would be great if you could share the data.table way. I'd not seen that package before. Looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the data.table package and doing some preliminaries...

```
require(data.table)
n0<- 1e5
n <- 1e6
DT <- data.table(A1 = sample(1:n0, n, replace = TRUE),B1 = sample(1:n0, n, replace = TRUE))
```

this does the trick.

```
setkey(DT,A1)
DT[
    DT[,.N,by=A1],
    countC:=N
]
```

When you access a data.table with `DT[i,j]`, you can select rows with `i` and do something else with `j`, just like in data.frames.

`DT[,.N,by=A1]` selects all rows (since `i` is blank) and counts rows for each "A1" using the special variable `.N`.

After setting column "A1" as key for DT, we can pass a data.table -- in this case `DT[,.N,by=A1]` -- in `i` to merge back the information in the latter data.table. In `j`, we create a new column in DT using `countC:=N`. The three vignettes on [data.table's CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/) are a good place to start learning more about how this works.

**The question at hand.** Oh, I think I see what the original problem was. Suppose `unique(x)=c(1,2,4)`. If you try `table(x)[x]`, you will be trying to access `table(x)[1]`, `table(x)[2]` and `table(x)[4]`. The last one is undefined since the length of the table is only 3. R always returns `NA` when we access indices greater than the length of a vector. For example, look at `(1:3)[4]`.

In your case, if you are missing any unique values in `1:n0` that are not at the very top, you will see `NA`s.

Comment: Ok, I was about to say that I was wondering too, but I think I know why it happened (see edit).

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(500)
A <- data.frame(A1=sample(2:1000, 100000, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
B <- data.frame(B1=sample(1:1000, 100000, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
C <- cbind(A,B)
C$countC <- table(as.factor(C$A1))[C$A1]
 summary(C$countC)
```

Looking at this example, we find that the `NA`s occur at the `1000` "factor":

```
summary(C[is.na(C$countC),"A1"])
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1000    1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
```

I think your `A1` object has not filled in all the factors it could but after the `cbind` the `table` thinks it ought to and so runs out of factors by the time it gets to the end of your sample.

```
> str(C$A1)
 int [1:100000] 834 726 976 469 813 207 513 926 830 712 ...
> str(as.factor(C$A1))
 Factor w/ 999 levels "2","3","4","5",..: 833 725 975 468 812 206 512 925 829 711 ...
```

An obvious solution for this would be to just use `table(A$A1)` but I'm guessing you to produce the table from this new data frame.

Comment: Hugh, thanks for your response. It doesn't matter whether you treat the integers as factors or integers, the NA problem still gets in.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that appears to have worked is

C$countC <- table(C$A1)[as.character(C$A1)]

I was indexing by a numeric vector, where the names of the table are characters. Duh!